# LINQ to XML Selecting attribute values that are not equal to a value

Tags: linq-to-xml

Why isn't this working? I am trying to select attributes where the status values are not "0".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<response>
    <Auth status="0"></Auth>
    <Modify status="601"></Modify>
</response>
```

LINQ to XML

```
var errorcodeList = xml.Descendants("response")
                     .Where(x => x.Attribute("status").Value != "0")
                     .Select(x => x.Attribute("status").Value)
                     .ToList();
```

I was expecting to get "601" as a result but instead I get no elements at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a minor issue: you're trying to read the attributes of the `response` element.

The following code accesses the descendants of `response` and returns the correct value:

```
var errorcodeList = xml.Descendants("response")
                       .Descendants()
                       .Where(x => x.Attribute("status").Value != "0")
                       .Select(x => x.Attribute("status").Value)
                       .ToList();
```